# PSET5 Speller Huge Number of Misspelled Words

Tags: python-3.x, cs50

I have been running the solution but is getting a high number of misspelled words.
WORDS MISSPELLED:     15904 as compared to staff's WORDS MISSPELLED:     955

Other than that, the word count is accurate and the runtime is alright.
I suspect the problem might come from the check / load function but I am not sure what caused it.
Some other code implemented a "to lowercase" in the check function, but I thought the (strcasecmp) would have done the job of comparing between strings, disregarding the case.

Check Function

```
bool check(const char *word)
{

    int hashInt = hash(word);

    if (table[hashInt] == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    node *cursor = table[hashInt];

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {

        int i = strcasecmp(cursor -> word, word);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            return 0;
            break;
        }

        cursor = cursor -> next;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Load Function

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    char word [LENGTH + 1];

    while (fscanf(file, "%s\n", word) != EOF)
    {

        int hashInt = hash(word);

        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (n == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return 1;
        }



        if (table[hashInt] == NULL)
        {
            table[hashInt] = n;
        }
        else
        {
            n -> next = table[hashInt];
            table[hashInt] = n;
        }

        strcpy(n -> word, word);
        wordLoaded++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return true;
}
```

Hash Function

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ word[i];

    return hash % N;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the `hash` function take case into account?

Comment: No it doesn't. I think. Added Hash Function. I believe it just sieve though the words and hashing them

Answer (score 0):

From the spec:

> `dictionary` is assumed to be a file containing a list of lowercase
>   words

and

> Your implementation of check must be case-insensitive.

This `int i = strcasecmp(cursor -> word, word);` looks like it would fulfill the requirement *as long as* this `int hashInt = hash(word);` was also case insensitive. Alas, it is not;  hash("A") and hash("a") will return different values.